# Determining the orientation of a file in memory

Tags: python, file, io, bit-manipulation

Say I want to process a CSV file. I know in Python I can call the `read()` function to open the file and read it in a byte at a time, from the first field in the file (i.e. the field in the top left of the file) to the last field (the field in the bottom right).

My question is how I can determine the orientation of a file in memory. That is, if I view the contents of the file as a single binary number and process it as bit stream, how can I know if the first field (the field the `read()` first returns to us) is stored in the least significant positions of the binary number or the most significant positions? Would that be determined by the endianness of the machine my program is running on?

Here's one (contrived) instance where this distinction would matter. Say I first scanned the binary representation of the file from least significant position to most significant position to determine the widths of each of the CSV values. If I were to then call `read()`, the first field width I calculated would correspond to the first field `read()` returns if and only if the first field of the CSV file is stored at the least significant bit positions when we view the file as a single binary number. If the first field was instead stored at the most significant positions, I'd first have to reverse my list of calculated field widths before I could use it.

Here's a more concrete example:

CSV file: `abc,12345`

Scanned field widths: either `[3, 5]` or `[5, 3]` depending on how the CSV file is laid out in memory.

Now, if I call `read()`, the first field I'll process is `abc`. If `abc` happened to be the first field I scanned through when calculating the field widths, I'm good. I'll know that I've scanned the entire first field after reading `3` characters. However, if I first scanned `12345` when calculating the field widths, I've got a problem.

How can I determine how a file is laid out in memory? Is the first field of a file stored in the least significant bit positions, or the most significant bit positions?

Answer (score 1):

Endiannes is a problem of binary files. CSV file is a text file. The numbers are not binary numbers but ASCII characters. There is no endiannes in it.

Comment: But ASCII characters can be viewed as binary numbers. If you concatenate all the binary representations you get a binary version of the CSV file. That kind of representation is a constraint of the problem.

Comment: Endiannes describes ordering of bytes in multibyte numbers. ASCII characters are single byte.

Comment: If you write sequence of numbers 0x0004 0x2771 0x5632, they will always be written in this order, the numbers are never reversed. Endiannes describes how bytes inside these numbers are ordered, it can be 0004 2771 5632, 4000 1772 2365 or 0400 7172 3256. If you write 12345 in ASCII, it's always 12345 because they are treated as sequence of one-byte numbers: 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34 0x35.

Comment: So endianness *only* refers the the ordering of bytes in a number? There'd never be a case where in one architecture the numbers are laid out in memory like 0x0004 0x2771 0x5632 and in another they're laid out as 0x5632 0x2771 0x0004  ?

Comment: I could convert the CSV file to an integer like this: `int.from_bytes(csv_byte_stream.encode(), 'little')`. The final argument could be `big`. With this approach, endianess would matter, right?

Comment: Yes, endianness refers to ordering of bytes inside one number. Multiple numbers are always in the same sequence because reordering them does not offer any computational advantage and will make any ordered processing very difficult. The conversion tries to interpret the CSV as binary file of four-byte numbers. To read the number from ASCII string, use `int(string)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146310/discussion-between-adam-and-stensoft).